# How to: Upgrade java on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: java

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my computer after that I installed Java and now I want to update the current version of java.

Current Version is **jdk-8u11** and i want to upgrade it to **jdk-8u112**.

Can someone please tell me that how to upgrade it?

Please consider that I am new to Ubuntu.

Comment: Are you using the java from Ubuntu repo ?

Comment: What is the output of this command: java -version

Answer (score 1):

I assume you install java from `ppa:webupd8team/java`. But actually last version of java is still `jdk-8u111`. If you want use `jdk-8u112` version, you can install it by downloading their binary and creating symlink.

- Remove/uninstall jdk-8u111
- Download 8u112 binary from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)
- Uncompress, move to /usr/java

  ```
  sudo tar xvzf jdk-8u112-linux-i586.tar.gz -C /usr/java
  ```

Now to set your JAVA_HOME environment variable:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_05/
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java ${JAVA_HOME%*/}/bin/java 20000
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac ${JAVA_HOME%*/}/bin/javac 20000
```

Make sure the Oracle's java is set as default java by:

```
update-alternatives --config java
```

Confirm your recent java version

```
java -version
```